# How to create a 3D array/matrix in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, matrix

I am trying to create a 3D array which will store an image's height, width, and RGB values as the dimensions of matrix/array.
Here is what I am trying:

```
var array = Array<Array<Array<Int>>>()
var testArray = [[[Int]]] ()
```

Now that I have initialize these arrays, how would I set a specific number of rows and columns?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to add the appropriate number of objects to each array  - use nested loops

Comment: Okay. Could you give an example of making 10 x 20 x 30 array please? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until fixed length arrays are supported in Swift, I'd do it something like this:

```
let zArry = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10)
let yArry = [[Int]](repeating: zArry, count: 20)
let xArry = [[[Int]]](repeating: yArry, count: 30)

let val = xArry[2][1][1]
```

Comment: You can't use `repeatedValue` as it will put the same `zArry` in every element of `yArry` and the same `yArry` in every element of `xArry`

Comment: Are you sure?  The documentation states that "repeatedValue" "Construct a Array of `count` elements, each initialized to `repeatedValue`".  Ints are a value type..it shouldn't be utilizing references.

Comment: You're right - Because arrays are structs, they are copied.  It wouldn't work if the array was an object.

Comment: The fact that arrays are value types is probably going to trip someone up, if anything was going to. Regardless, everything from the Ints to the Arrays are value types in this snippet.  The snippet would not work if Arrays were reference types (as you stated) but it would also not work if the Ints were reference types.  **Both of those types need to be value types for this to work (which they are).**

Comment: Does `xArry[2][1][1]` return 2 in zArry, 1 in yArry, and 1 in xArry?

Comment: Close, but backwards ;)  xArray[x][y][z].  2 in x, 1 in y, 1 in z.